# Find Maximum abs. value for each group of row index, Arrange max. values diagonally in matrix, non diagonal values as per indexes,find determinant

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, max

I am new to Python.

I want to find the largest values from all the columns for group of same row indexes (i.e. 5 to 130, beignning with 5), and also show its row and column index label in output. The largest values can be positive as well as negative (+ or -)

There should not be duplicates for row indexes in different groups. i.e. one row index for one group.

P.S.- If two groups have max. values in same row indexes, then consider next largest value of different row index.

After finding largest from each group, arrange those values diagonally in square matrix. Then fill the remaining non diagonal values with the corresponding values of column indexes for each group from the main dataframe and find its Determinant.

My dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
    {'0_deg': [2, 11, 21, -17, 5, 40, 22, 7, 20, -6, -6, -6, 24, 21, 20, 61, 21, 5, 2, 17], 
     '10_deg': [12, -21, 11, 1, 4, -2, 33, 53, 18, 10, -3, -1, 23, 18, 23, 8, 11, -25, 21, -14], 
     '20_deg': [23, -10, 3, 20, -41, 13, 10, 5, -9, 7, -4, -21, 14, -26, -31, 9, 1, -15, 3, -6], 
     '30_deg': [12, 9, -5, 4, 9, -46, 1, -8, -27, 3, -9, -14, 15, -6, 14, 7, -11, 5, 19, -4]}, index=[5, 10, 12, 101, 130, 5, 10, 12, 101, 130, 5, 10, 12, 101, 130, 5, 10, 12, 101, 130])
```

New Dataframe: **Float Values instead of Integer**

[image: float]

```
data_dict ={'0_deg': [3.30E-05, 2.34E-05, 1.59E-05, 1.08E-06, 1.93E-05, 2.30E-06, -9.20E-05, 5.20E-05, 1.90E-06, 2.12E-05, 2.02E-05, 1.62E-05, -8.20E-05, 1.60E-06, 1.44E-05, 1.62E-05, 8.85E-07, -2.45E-05, -4.05E-06, -1.92E-05], 
   '10_deg': [1.23E-05, -2.11E-05, -2.03E-06, 5.04E-06, 7.87E-06, 4.51E-06, 9.41E-06, -1.04E-05, -1.85E-05, -6.19E-06, 1.19E-05, 2.01E-05, 4.30E-06, 3.66E-06, 5.21E-06, -3.32E-06, 4.02E-06, 2.00E-05, 8.73E-07, 2.41E-05], 
   '20_deg': [7.10E-06, 1.63E-05, 4.12E-05, -6.37E-06, 1.52E-06, 9.65E-06, 4.14E-06, -4.51E-05, -1.82E-05, -7.86E-05, 7.16E-05, 7.00E-05, 6.70E-06, 4.54E-07, 5.55E-07, 6.45E-06, 5.69E-06, 1.00E-05, -5.65E-06, 3.00E-05], 
   '30_deg': [-3.20E-06, 3.54E-05, 6.21E-05, 5.10E-07, -1.20E-05, 1.14E-05, 4.19E-05, -1.23E-05, -9.11E-05, 4.20E-05, -1.52E-05, -1.00E-06, 2.06E-06, 3.33E-06, 2.30E-06, 1.41E-05, 3.62E-05, 3.90E-05, -1.56E-05, 4.00E-06],
  }
```

Output with float values with the following error:

In the code only the data type is changed to float
`dtype=np.float32`

This gives me **EXPECTED OUTPUT 1:**

But for filling the Matrix and finding out the Determinant it is showing the following **error**. Also if I try to add one more Group from 4 to 5, or if I add 1 more the Column Index, I am getting the **same error**. I want to implement the code for 15 groups, with 100 indexes each.

```
while idx[idx_angle_number[0][0]] in repeating_row_idx:
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

[image: Output]

Actual Output:

[image: Actual]

In my actual output, index 130 is repeating for 2 groups, in such case consider next higher value of another index.

Expected Output 1:

[image: Exp1]

Expected Output 2:

[image: exp2]

Expected Output 3:

[image: exp3]

Code I tried :

```
df = pd.read_csv ('Matrixfile.csv')
df = df.set_index('Index')

def f(x):
    x1 = x.abs().stack()
    x2 = x.stack()
    x = x2.iloc[np.argsort(-x1)].head(1)
    return x

groups = (df.index == 5).cumsum()
df1 = df.groupby(groups).apply(f).reset_index(level=[1,2])
df1.columns = ['Index','Angle','Value']

print (df1)
df1.to_csv('Matrix_OP.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=True)
```

Another code I tried:

```
import numpy as np

# INPUT
data_dict ={'0_deg': [43, 50, 45, -17, 5, 19, 11, 32, 36, 41, 19, 11, 32, 36, 1, 19, 7, 1, 36, 10], 
   '10_deg': [47, 41, 46, -18, 4, 16, 12, 34, -52, 31, 16, 12, 34, -71, 2, 9, 52, 34, -6, 9], 
   '20_deg': [46, 43, -56, 29, 6, 14, 13, 33, 43, 6, 14, 13, 37, 43, 3, 14, 13, 25, 40, 8], 
   '30_deg': [-46, 16, -40, -11, 9, 15, 33, -39, -22, 21, 15, 63, -39, -22, 4, 6, 25, -39, -22, 7],
   }

# Row idx of a group in this list
idx = [5, 10, 12, 101, 130]


# Getting some dimensions and sorting the data
row_idx_length = len(idx) 
group_length = len(data_dict['0_deg'])
number_of_groups = len(data_dict.keys())  
idx = idx*number_of_groups   
data_arr = np.zeros((group_length,number_of_groups),dtype=np.int32) 
#
col = 0
keys = []
for key in sorted(data_dict):
    data_arr[:,col] = data_dict[key]
    keys.append(key)
    col+=1

def get_max_value_group(arr):
    # function to find maximum absolute value of a 2d array
    max_values = []
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        max_value = max(abs(arr[i]))
        max_values.append(max_value)
    return max(max_values) 

# For output 1
max_values = []  
for i in range(0,row_idx_length*number_of_groups,row_idx_length):
    # get the max value for the current group
    value = get_max_value_group(data_arr[i:i+row_idx_length])
    # get the row and column idx associated with the max value
    idx_angle_number = np.nonzero(abs(data_arr[i:i+row_idx_length,:])==value)
    print('Group number : ' + str(i//row_idx_length+1))
    print('Number : '+ str(idx[idx_angle_number[0][0]]))
    print('Angle : '+ keys[idx_angle_number[1][0]])
    print('Absolute value : ' + str(value))   
    print('------')
    max_values.append(value)

# Arrange those values diagonally in square matrix for output 2
A = np.diag(max_values)   
print('A = ' + str(A))

# Fill A with desired values
for i in range(0,number_of_groups,1):
    A[i,0] = data_arr[i*row_idx_length+2,2]   # 20 deg 12
    A[i,1:3] = data_arr[i*row_idx_length+3,1] # x2 : 10 deg 101
    A[i,3] = data_arr[i*row_idx_length+1,1]   # 10 deg 10

# Final output
# replace the diagonal of A with max values
# get the idx of diag
A_di = np.diag_indices(number_of_groups)
# replace with max values
A[A_di] = max_values
print ('A = ' + str(A)) 

# Compute determinant of A
det_A = np.linalg.det(A)
print ('det(A) = '+str(det_A))
```

Request for support from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add the following modifications :

*The function find the absolute extrema and not max(abs()).

*During the search, I add a test to avoid idx repetition.

*The filling of A for final output is now based on result of output 1

```
import numpy as np

# INPUT
data_dict ={'0_deg': [2, 11, 21, -17, 5, 40, 22, 7, 20, -6, -6, -6, 24,     21, 20, 61, 21, 5, 2, 17], 
 '10_deg': [12, -21, 11, 1, 4, -2, 33, 53, 18, 10, -3, -1, 23, 18, 23, 8, 11, -25, 21, -14], 
 '20_deg': [23, -10, 3, 20, -41, 13, 10, 5, -9, 7, -4, -21, 14, -26, -31, 9, 1, -15, 3, -6], 
 '30_deg': [12, 9, -5, 4, 9, -46, 1, -8, -27, 3, -9, -14, 15, -6, 14, 7, -11, 5, 19, -4]}

# row idx of a group in this list
idx = [5, 10, 12, 101, 130]


# getting some dimensions and sorting the data
row_idx_length = len(idx) 
group_length = len(data_dict['0_deg'])
number_of_groups = len(data_dict.keys())  
idx = idx*number_of_groups   
data_arr = np.zeros((group_length,number_of_groups),dtype=np.int32) 
#
col = 0
keys = []
for key in sorted(data_dict):
    data_arr[:,col] = data_dict[key]
    keys.append(key)
    col+=1 
# just a similar array for repeatition test    
data_arr_repeat = np.copy(data_arr)

def get_extrema_value_group(arr):
    # function to find absolute extrema value of a 2d array
    extrema = 0
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        max_value = max(arr[i])
        min_value = min(arr[i])
        if (abs(min_value) > max_value) and (abs(extrema) < abs(min_value)):
            extrema = min_value
        elif (abs(min_value) < max_value) and (abs(extrema) < max_value):
            extrema = max_value         
    return extrema 

# for output 1
max_values = []  
# for repeatition and A filling
sorted_number = []
sorted_angle = []
for i in range(0,row_idx_length*number_of_groups,row_idx_length):
    # get the max value for the current group
    value = get_extrema_value_group(data_arr[i:i+row_idx_length])
    # get the row and column idx associated with the max value
    idx_angle_number = np.nonzero(data_arr[i:i+row_idx_length,:]==value)
    #
    # test for repetition
    while idx[idx_angle_number[0][0]] in sorted_number:
        print('>> Extrema '+str(value)+' got repeating idx ' + str(idx[idx_angle_number[0][0]]) + ' : next higher value of another index will be considered')
        # set data_arr repeating value to 0 to exclude it
        data_arr_repeat[i+idx_angle_number[0][0],idx_angle_number[1][0]] = 0
        # get the NEW max value for the current group
        value = get_extrema_value_group(data_arr_repeat[i:i+row_idx_length])
        # get the row and column idx associated with the max value
        idx_angle_number = np.nonzero(data_arr_repeat[i:i+row_idx_length,:]==value)    
    #
    print('Group number : ' + str(i//row_idx_length+1))
    print('Number : '+ str(idx[idx_angle_number[0][0]]))
    print('Angle : '+ keys[idx_angle_number[1][0]])
    print('Absolute extrema value : ' + str(value))   
    print('------')
    max_values.append(value)
    sorted_number.append(idx_angle_number[0][0])
    sorted_angle.append(idx_angle_number[1][0])


# arrange those values diagonally in square matrix for output 2
A = np.diag(max_values)   
print('A = ' + str(A))

# fill A with desired values based on sorted_number and sorted_angle
for i in range(0,number_of_groups,1):
    for j in range(0,number_of_groups,1):
        A[j,i] = data_arr[j*row_idx_length+sorted_number[i],sorted_angle[i]]

# Final output
# replace the diagonal of A with max values
# get the idx of diag
A_di = np.diag_indices(len(max_values))
# replace with max values
A[A_di] = max_values
print ('A = ' + str(A)) 

# Compute determinant of A
det_A = np.linalg.det(A)
print ('det(A) = '+str(det_A))
```

Global output :

```
Group number : 1
Number : 130
Angle : 20_deg
Absolute extrema value : -41
------
Group number : 2
Number : 12
Angle : 10_deg
Absolute extrema value : 53
------
>> Extrema -31 got repeating idx 130 : next higher value of another index will be considered
Group number : 3
Number : 101
Angle : 20_deg
Absolute extrema value : -26
------
Group number : 4
Number : 5
Angle : 0_deg
Absolute extrema value : 61
------
A = [[-41   0   0   0]
     [  0  53   0   0]
     [  0   0 -26   0]
     [  0   0   0  61]]
A = [[-41  11  20   2]
     [  7  53  -9  40]
     [-31  23 -26  -6]
     [ -6 -25   3  61]]
det(A) = 7265430.000000008
```

Comment: Eg. My A11 diagonal value for group 1 is ```-41```, which is at Index ```130``` ```20_deg```.  So my A21 should be same ```130```,```20_deg``` value, of group 2 i.e. ```7``` , A31 should be of ```130```,```20_deg``` of group 3 i.e. ```-31```..and so on.. If you go next, my A22 diagonal value is of ```12```,```10_deg``` of group 2, i.e.```53```.. so A12 will be ```12```,```10_deg``` of group 1..i.e```11```, A23 be ```12```,```10_deg``` of group 3 i.e. ```23```..and so on..

Comment: You have provided great support for my problem, just request you to help with 1 minute edit. In #filling Matrix A with desired values part of code,the values have been entered manually. ``` A[i,0] = data_arr[i*row_idx_length+4,2]``` Here, +4,2 have been entered manually, But for a 15x15 matrix this is no easy task to fill each position manually. So could you help me with this, to fill non diagonal values with repsect to indexes or other way please

Comment: Just edited, tell me now if it's working with bigger matrix.

Comment: Its working if I have 5 groups, 5 Columns, or if 6 groups & 6 columns, But if I add another column, I get the error:  ```while idx[idx_angle_number[0][0]] in repeating_row_idx:
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0```.

Comment: I tried the code on my complete matrix of 15 groups, I am getting Only the **Output 1** after which i am getting the above Index Error, could you suggest some modification to your code???

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
# groups of rows
g = df.groupby(df.index.to_series().eq(5).cumsum())

r_list = []
cols = []
for i, v in g:
    r,c = v.drop(r_list).abs().stack().idxmax()
    r_list.append(r)
    cols.append(df.loc[r,c].values)

np.array(cols)
```

Output:

```
array([[-41,   7, -31,  -6],
       [ 11,  53,  23, -25],
       [ 20,  -9, -26,   3],
       [  2,  40,  -6,  61]], dtype=int64)
```

and determinant:

```
np.linalg.det(cols)
# 7265430.000000008
```